# Поиск слова из списка в Memo

Tags: delphi, поиск

Как реализовать поиск в строке Memo из списка слов

Написал функцию поиска слова из списка

```
function scan(s:string):integer;
begin
result:= pos('слово1',s) or pos('слово2',s) or pos('слово 3',s);
end;
```

Реализация.

```
if scan(memo1.Lines[0]) <> 1 then
begin
 {Записать найденное слово, например, в массив}
 mas[i]:=
end;
```

P.S. заведомо известно, что в каждой строке встретится только одно из искомых слов

В итоге должно получиться: 
искомые слова: delphi, text, программирование

s:='вывести слово delphi';

mas[i] будет равен delphi

Comment: Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос в виде вопроса, а не задания.

Comment: Догадываюсь, что первое предложение является вопросительным. Однако, здесь не детский сад. Кого Вы надеетесь облапошить? По существу, качество Вашего вопроса не улучшилось. Что конкретно вызывает трудность? Подсказка: какой результат Вы ожидаете от операции - `pos('слово1',s) or pos('слово2',s) or pos('слово 3',s);`?

Comment: @Igor что Вы имеете ввиду под словом облапошить? Да, я знаю, что функция возвращает 1 или 0. Трудность именно в этом. И скорее всего реализовать можно и без функции pos. Если бы не нужно было выводить какое слово было найдено, я бы не писал сюда. А нужно именно вывести какие слово из этих встретились в строке

Comment: "Да, я знаю, что функция возвращает 1 или 0." - Какая функция? Функция `Pos` возвращает ближайший к началу строки индех подстроки (1-based) или 0, если подстрока не найдена.

Comment: "облапошить" - обвести вокруг пальца, одурачить, обдурить, объегорить. Вы поменяли слово "Нужно" на слово "Как", но качество вопроса этим не повысили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `scan` должна возвращать найденное слово, а не его позицию в строке:

```
function scan(s: string): string;
var
  Position: Integer;
const
  WORD_1 = 'слово1';
  WORD_2 = 'слово2';
  WORD_3 = 'слово 3';
begin
  Position := pos(WORD_1, s);
  if Position > 0 then
    Result := copy(s, Position, Length(WORD_1))
  else
  begin
    Position := pos(WORD_2, s);
    if Position > 0 then
      Result := copy(s, Position, Length(WORD_2))
    else
    begin
      Position := pos(WORD_3, s);
      if Position > 0 then
        Result := copy(s, Position, Length(WORD_3))
      else
        Result := ''; // не нашли
    end;
  end;
end;
```

А дальше делаете цикл по всем строкам в `memo1` и `mas[i] := scan(memo1.Lines[i])`.